# Do I need to sanitize a file name in $_POST before getting it with curl?

Tags: php, security, curl

The var is only the file name portion of the full file spec.

For example:

```
$file = $_POST['name'];
curl_exec("https:/example.com/some_api/".$file.".json");
```

Incidentally, all *valid* requests will be posted from one domain.

Comment: @Pekka I left out curl_init and options for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to sanitize (for safety) in that this can cause security problems (`curl` probably already handles anything like that) but you may need to `urlencode` it for it to work.  On the other hand, you may need to *not* `urlencode` it, but since `_POST` parameters are `urldecode`d automatically that would require an initial double-encoding.

By the way, this is wrong.  You need to `curl_exec` on a `curl` resource, not a URL.  You want `curl_exec(curl_init($url))` (but you may need to set options and stuff like that).

Answer (score 0):

Just for safety purposes, you may want to `urlencode()` it.

```
$file = urlencode($_POST['name']);
```

That way, if someone tries something fancy, it will be safer.